# How to cluster paths in order to discover working area shape?

Tags: clustering

I have a robot that moves in a 2D space and records its position in time as a list of (x,y) coordinates. The 2D space is divided in sub-areas that cannot be automatically crossed. When a given event occurs (e.g. the robot is taken and manually moved), the list of coordinates (let's call it path) is saved and another one is initialized. In an ideal case, each path is contained in only one sub-area.

Given a list of paths, I want to cluster them in order to discover how many sub-areas are there in the 2D space, and their shape. I'm using a custom algorithm that computes the alpha-shape (convex hull) of each path and iteratively merges the resulting polygons based on their overlap. When no more merges occur, the algorithm ends. The alpha shape of the merged areas is then computed.

The problem is that even one bad path (e.g. due to positioning errors) is sufficient to produce a bad result. Are there known algorithms that address this problem? I'm attaching an example of my case. In the second image, I drew the paths on a grid in order to visually detect outliers. A single path is highlighted in white.

[image][image]